# How can I send headless Selenium RC tests via an external proxy server?

Tags: proxy, selenium

I need to use Selenium RC on a headless Ubuntu server to run tests against a website using an external proxy server to simulate a user in a different country.

To test the process, I've created a really simple PHPUnit test script, which basically does:

```
$this->setBrowser("*firefox");
$this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.ipchicken.com/");
$this->open("/");
$this->assertTrue($this->isTextPresent(<proxy ip>));
```

I start my Selenium RC using these proxy server directives (there's no authentication on the proxy):

```
export DISPLAY=":99" && java -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy ip> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port> -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -avoidProxy
```

but my test script fails the assertion. If I change the test to assert for my Selenium server IP address, the assertion passes, which makes it look to me as though Selenium is sending the "open" request directly to ipchicken.com, and not sending it through the proxy server.

The selenium server can access the proxy server OK - I've tested this with a simple PHP Curl script. If I request ipchicken.com using Curl through the proxy server, it returns the proxy server IP address just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same issue trying to get a proxy to work on an Ubuntu system and was unable to get the *-Dhttp.proxyHost* etc... settings to work.  My solution was to export http_proxy prior to the *java* command - just like you're doing with the DISPLAY.

```
export http_proxy = http://username:password@host:port
```

**Update:**  Since you are using firefox, you'll also need to set appropriate proxy settings within firefox.  (The *hang* you mention in your comment is firefox failing to go through the proxy).  You'll need to run the firefox profilemanager with

```
firefox -ProfileManager
```

then create a new profile.  Create a new directory for the profile's path since it will put a large number of files in that location.  Within that profile create the appropriate proxy settings.  You can now use the *firefoxProfileTemplate* option with the selenium rc:

```
 java -jar ..... -firefoxProfileTemplate /path/to/your/new/profile
```

Note that you'll only need to run the profile manager once, so thereafter you'll be able to run headless.

Comment: Thanks - it's a nice idea, but this causes the RC server to hang at the "Launching Firefox" stage. If I try "export http_proxy=host:port" (i.e. without the http:// prefix) the RC server works OK, but still doesn't use the proxy.

Comment: Perfect - thanks! As a side-note to anyone else struggling with this, I was originally using Selenium v2.0b2, which failed to start Firefox with a real user profile. Upgrading to Selenium v2.0rc3 fixed this for me, although I think it was actually fixed in v2.0b3.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain in short using Selenium Grid
1. First start the display on using Xorg:96 -ac on Linux
2. Now export the DISPLAY=96.
3. start firefox
4. Start the Selenium Port using selenium grid.
The Above steps should be done on Linux Server.

1. Before starting the selenium server on linux start the **hub** on your machine.
2. Now execute the the script it will go to the active port on linux.

Thanks